# Incorrect CSS Blur Rendering When Clipped in Chrome When Hardware Accelerated

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transforms, css-filters

I'm having an issue with `filter: blur()` on Chrome.  I've used `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` to encourage hardware acceleration and it has greatly improved performance (I'm using it sparingly).  I have an element, and I've set its `before` to have a background image and a blur.  I've set its extents to be outside the bounds of its containing element.

[image: Incorrect on the left, correct on the right. Notice that it is inset]

Above is a screenshot of what happens in Chrome.  The hardware accelerated version is on the left, while the non-hardware accelerated is on the right.  Notice that on the left, the blur appears inset with soft edges.

It appears that in Chrome, when hardware accelerated, the element is clipped with an overflow before being blurred, causing the feathered edges.

Other than disabling hardware acceleration, which decimates performance with this large-radius blur, is there a way to encourage Chrome to perform the blur before clipping?

I've attached an example test case below.

### Thanks!

```css
      div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        overflow: hidden;
        border: 2px solid red;
      }

      div::before {
        background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Van_Gogh_-_Starry_Night_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/1024px-Van_Gogh_-_Starry_Night_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg);
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: -200px;
        top: -200px;
        width: calc(100% + 400px);
        height: calc(100% + 400px);
        background-size: calc(100% + 400px) calc(100% + 400px);

        filter: blur(60px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(60px);
        z-index: 1;
      }

      #incorrect::before {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      }

      #incorrect {
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px;
      }

      #correct {
        right: 100px;
        top: 100px;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="incorrect"></div>
    <div id="correct"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Moving the `transform` to the `#incorrect` seems to fix the problem, but is it hardware accelerated?

Comment: The fact that the actual result is different is really interesting.

Comment: This still seems to be an issue 6 years later. I've made an issue in the chromium bug tracker, hopefully it will be fixed in the future: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1294410

Answer (score -1):

You could try setting the last property "translation-value-z" on the `#incorrect::before` to 1. I dunno why exactly, but it seemed to work.

> Translation-value-z is the third vector value and defines the
>   translation in the direction of the z-axis (3rd dimension). Attention:
>   It can only be a length value, percentage is not supported.

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d

```css
      div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        overflow: hidden;
        border: 2px solid red;
      }

      div::before {
        background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Van_Gogh_-_Starry_Night_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/1024px-Van_Gogh_-_Starry_Night_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg);
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: -200px;
        top: -200px;
        width: calc(100% + 400px);
        height: calc(100% + 400px);
        background-size: calc(100% + 400px) calc(100% + 400px);

        filter: blur(60px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(60px);
        z-index: 1;
      }

      #incorrect::before {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1);
      }

      #incorrect {
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px;
      }

      #correct {
        right: 100px;
        top: 100px;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="incorrect"></div>
    <div id="correct"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Setting the z-axis to 1 stops forcing the element to be HW accelerated, so this isn't actually fixing the issue